# Exact number of vectors in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I was doing some practice questions in my book and I was asked T/F if there are real vector spaces containing exactly seven vectors. I was thinking that this is True, but the books tells me that the right answer is False. Why is this so? Thanks!

Comment: Because a vector space is closed under scalar multiplication, you have a uncountably infinite amount of vectors since each can be scaled by an $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Kamster unless it's dimension 0, but then there's just one vector.

Comment: nice catch Matt S. that is true also

Comment: Hello, can you guys please expand on this? I understand the requirements for scalar multiplication and vector addition but I'm having a hard time understanding what you just said. Can you please give an example?

Comment: Does this mean that any number of vectors will always fail to be in a vector space?

Comment: I'll take this vector of maximal norm... and double it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every vector space (besides the trivial zero space) has **infinitely** many vectors in it, since for any vector in the vector space,  we can always find another vector in the vector space by multiplying by a real number (this is because vector spaces are closed under scalar multiplication), and we know that there are infinitely many real numbers, so it follows that there would be infinitely many vectors.

If I told you that $\vec{u}\in V$, and I asked you to tell me another vector in the space, you could tell me $2\vec{u}$ or $3\vec{u}$ or $2.333344\vec{u}$, etc...